Google OAuth login not working on web app with C# backend and Angular frontend
I have a pretty standard C# web app. Everything in the backend seems to be working, as I've tested it multiple times. Now, I'm trying to add a frontend UI to it using the Angular framework.
I have added a navbar component, which should display "Login" if the user is not logged in, and "Logout" if the user is logged in. Currently, when I press "Login" I am sent to the Google OAuth process and, when I finish it, the frontend still shows that I am not logged in.
Here's all the relevant code.
Backend
Startup.cs:
namespace g62.backofficeWebApplication
{
    public class Startup
    {
        readonly bool DoBootstrap = false;
        readonly bool DropTables = false; // not recomended to turn true without DoBootstrap also turning true
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AllowAngularLocalhost", policy =>
                {
                    policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200") 
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowCredentials();
                });
            });

            services.AddControllers();

            services.AddDbContext<EFContext>(options =>
            options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(8, 0, 0))
            ).ReplaceService<IValueConverterSelector, StronglyEntityIdValueConverterSelector>());

            services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
            services.AddSwaggerGen();
            
            services.AddAuthentication(options => {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie()
            .AddGoogle(options =>{
                options.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
                options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
            });
            services.AddAuthorization();

            services.AddScoped<Bootstrap>();
            services.AddAuthorization(options => {
                options.AddPolicy("RequireAdminRole", policy => policy.RequireRole("Admin"));
                options.AddPolicy("RequireDoctorRole", policy => policy.RequireRole("Admin"));
            });

            ConfigureMyServices(services);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, Bootstrap bootstrap)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI();
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseCors("AllowAngularLocalhost");

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });

            if (DropTables) {
                bootstrap.DropTables();
            }
            if (DoBootstrap) {
                bootstrap.DoBootstrap();
            }
        }

        public void ConfigureMyServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddTransient<IPatientRepository,PatientRepository>();
            services.AddTransient<PatientService>();
            services.AddTransient<PatientDTOMapper>();

            services.AddTransient<IStaffRepository,StaffRepository>();
            services.AddTransient<StaffService>();
            services.AddTransient<StaffDtoMapper>();

            services.AddTransient<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
            services.AddTransient<UserService>();
            services.AddTransient<UserDtoMapper>();

            services.AddTransient<IOperationRequestRepository,OperationRequestRepository>();
            services.AddTransient<OperationRequestService>();
            services.AddTransient<OperationRequestDTOMapper>();
            services.AddTransient<OperationRequestFactory>();

            services.AddTransient<IPendingActionRepository,PendingActionRepository>();

            services.AddTransient<ILogsRepository,LogsRepository>();
            services.AddTransient(typeof(Domain.Logs.Logger<>));

            services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork,UnitOfWork>();

            services.AddTransient<PendingActionsManager>();
            services.AddTransient<NotificationService>();
            services.AddTransient<NotificationSender,GoogleEmailSender>();

            services.AddTransient<WhoAmIService>();
        }
    }
}

LoginController.cs:
namespace g62.backofficeWebApplication.Controllers {
    public class LoginController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly UserService _service;

        public LoginController(UserService service)
        {
            _service = service;
        }

        [HttpGet("login")]
        public IActionResult Login()
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                Redirect("http://localhost:4200/");
            }

            var properties = new AuthenticationProperties{RedirectUri = Url.Action("GoogleResponse", "Login")};
            return Challenge(properties, GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        }


        [HttpGet("logout")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
        {
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            Console.WriteLine("Logged out.");
            return Redirect("http://localhost:4200/");
        }

        [HttpGet("GoogleResponse")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GoogleResponse()
        {
            var authenticateResult = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

            if (!authenticateResult.Succeeded)
                return BadRequest("Authentication failed.");

            var userName = authenticateResult.Principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value;
            var email = authenticateResult.Principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email)?.Value;

            try
            {
                var user = await _service.GetByEmailAsync(email);

                if (user.Active == "False")
                {
                    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                    return Redirect("http://localhost:4200/");
                }

                var claims = new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userName),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, email),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, user.Role.ToString())
                };

                var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
                {
                    IsPersistent = true,
                    ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(2)
                };

                await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
                    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                    new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity),
                    authProperties);

                // Redirect the user to the frontend application
                return Redirect("http://localhost:4200/");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                return Redirect("http://localhost:4200/");
            }
        }

        [HttpGet("status")]
        public IActionResult GetStatus()
        {
            if (HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return Ok(new
                {
                    isAuthenticated = true,
                    userName = HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value,
                    email = HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email)?.Value,
                    role = HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Role)?.Value
                });
            }
            else
            {
                return Ok(new { isAuthenticated = false });
            }
        }
    }
}

Frontend
auth.service.ts:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

interface AuthStatus {
  isAuthenticated: boolean;
  userName?: string;
  email?: string;
  role?: string;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  private apiUrl = 'https://your-backend-url.com'; // Replace with your backend URL
  private userInfo: { userName: string; email: string; role: string } | null = null;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  login(): void {
    window.location.href = `${this.apiUrl}/login`;
  }

  logout(): Observable<void> {
    return this.http.get<void>(`${this.apiUrl}/logout`, { withCredentials: true }).pipe(
      tap(() => {
        this.userInfo = null;
      }),
      catchError(this.handleError<void>('logout'))
    );
  }

  getStatus(): Observable<AuthStatus> {
    return this.http.get<AuthStatus>(`${this.apiUrl}/status`, { withCredentials: true }).pipe(
      tap((response) => {
        if (response.isAuthenticated) {
          this.userInfo = {
            userName: response.userName || '',
            email: response.email || '',
            role: response.role || ''
          };
        } else {
          this.userInfo = null;
        }
      }),
      catchError(this.handleError<AuthStatus>('getStatus', { isAuthenticated: false }))
    );
  }

  getUserInfo(): { userName: string; email: string; role: string } | null {
    return this.userInfo;
  }

  private handleError<T>(operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {
      console.error(`${operation} failed: ${error.message}`);
      return of(result as T);
    };
  }
}

navbar.component.ts:
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../core/services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
  isLoggedIn = false;
  userInfo: { userName: string; email: string; role: string } | null = null;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.authService.getStatus().subscribe({
      next: (response) => {
        this.isLoggedIn = response.isAuthenticated;
        this.userInfo = response.userInfo || null;
      },
      error: (err) => {
        console.error('Error checking login status', err);
      }
    });
  }

  login(): void {
    this.authService.login();
  }

  logout(): void {
    this.authService.logout().subscribe({
      next: () => {
        this.isLoggedIn = false;
        this.userInfo = null;
      },
      error: (err) => {
        console.error('Error logging out', err);
      }
    });
  }
}

navbar.component.html:
<nav class="navbar">
  <a class="navbar-logo" href="/">Website</a>
  <ul class="navbar-links">
    <li *ngIf="!isLoggedIn"><a href="#" (click)="login()">Login</a></li>
    <li *ngIf="isLoggedIn">
      <a href="#" (click)="logout()">Logout</a>
      <span *ngIf="userInfo">Welcome, {{ userInfo.userName }}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>


You will typically have problem with OpenID-Connect/OAuth over HTTP, try to use HTTPS, a common problem is the cookies. I blogged about troubleshooting cookie problems at https://nestenius.se/net/debugging-cookie-problems/
